# Images are not displayed on github pages/github.io

Tags: markdown, github-pages

My images in the .markdown files are not displayed on site, but they are displayed well locally and in the repository.

Please see my github.io repository:
https://github.com/TravisBAO/travisbao.github.io/blob/main/docs/_posts/2023-01-18-SSHKey.markdown

And if open the github page, they are not there:
https://travisbao.github.io/2023/01/19/SSHKey.html

I try all the potential solutions:

1. use the html format
2. change the location of the file
3. change the .PNG to .JPG

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there, all you need to do is to use the correct uri for the source. Your images are located at `"/assets/images/{filename}"`.

In the screenshot below, I edited the path that the image tags pointed to and was able to get the images to load correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cameron! It works.
I modify it like yours. Although it isn't displayed on the repository, it is displayed well on the website.

Comment: I'm concerned about why it behaves like this. And further more, I suppose it would confuse me when I edit the markdown file.

Comment: Ah that is because the markdown renderer on github and the website served via github-pages operate via different mechanisms. If you want to see what you site will look like before posting, you can clone your repo, set up Ruby on your computer, and then build the website locally with [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll)